# How to handle read and unread notification message on uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

How to confirm the messages received from notification is read or not.
Got list of notification from past 7 days displayed on `UITableView`.

How to handle the received message from notification is read or not.
Is it handle at client side only or server end.

Similar to mail box read or unread messages.

---

Answer (score 1):

A message is considered read when the user fully reads it , so it should be a server side as the user may log in from multiple devices , also this depends on your UI whether it shows part of it with a more button ( this case change status on click of button ) or completely shows it ( this case change status when the cell is shown ) , anyway when the user see it you need to change it's status in back end